# How to catch usercontrol event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, event-handling

I have a `usercontrol` that is a `container` for all my other `forms` but somehow the `events` raised within the container `usercontrol` are lost.

I have a `usercontrol button` and if I just put it on a page (not within my container `usercontrol`) i can handle its events. However, from within the container, neither `event` is handled nor `event` from a standard `asp:button` tag.
Thanks a lot!

Here is is the code:

Main `aspx` page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="Comanda.Login1" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Cosma" TagName="Form" Src="~/Form.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Cosma" TagName="Button" Src="~/CosmaButton.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <Cosma:Form ID="form" Title="Login" Width="500" Height="400" runat="server">
            <%-- TODO de adaugat buttoane si textboxuri --%>

            <div style="float:left;display:inline-block;margin-top:3%;width:170px; height:80%; border-right:2px solid #42458a;">
                <p>
                    lorem ipsum
                </p>
            </div>
            <asp:Table CssClass="loginTable" runat="server" ID="table">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label Text="Username: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label Text="Password: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                        <span style="float: right;">

                        </span>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
            <div style="float:right; display:inline-block; margin-top:120px;" >
                <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="Login"/>
            </div>
        </Cosma:Form>
    </div>
</form>
```

Code behind for main `aspx` page:

```
Public Class Login1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

     Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

     End Sub

     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

     End Sub

     Protected Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button.Click

     End Sub

End Class
```

And the `ascx` for the `user control`:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Form.ascx.vb" Inherits="Comanda.Form" %>
```

And finally the code-behind for the container `usercontrol`:

```
<ParseChildren(True, "ChildControls")>
Public Class Form
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    'TODO de ve nu merge sa raise event?
     Private WithEvents _panel As Panel
     Private _title As String
     Private _width As Double = 0D
     Private _height As Double = 0D
     Private _cssClass As String = "form"

Public Property Title As String
    Get
        Return _title
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If value IsNot "" Then
            _title = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Width As Double
    Get
        Return _width
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If value > 0 Then
            _width = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ChildControls As New List(Of Control)

Public Property Height As Double
    Get
        Return _height
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If value > 0 Then
            _height = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    'empty constructor
End Sub

Public Sub New(title As String)
    _title = title
End Sub


Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e As EventArgs)
    EnsureChildControls()

    _panel = New Panel()
    _panel.Attributes("class") = _cssClass
    If _width > 0 Then
        _panel.Width = New Unit(_width, UnitType.Pixel)
    End If

    If _height > 0 Then
        _panel.Height = New Unit(_height, UnitType.Pixel)
    End If

    Dim titlePanel As New Panel()
    titlePanel.Width = _panel.Width
    titlePanel.Height = New Unit(50, UnitType.Pixel)
    titlePanel.Style("background-color") = "#42458A"
    titlePanel.Style("text-align") = "left"

    Dim label As New Label()
    label.Text = _title
    label.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
    label.Style("margin-left") = "10px"
    titlePanel.Controls.Add(label)
    _panel.Controls.Add(titlePanel)

    For Each c As Control In ChildControls
        _panel.Controls.Add(c)
    Next

    Me.Controls.Add(_panel)

    MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Your question is too long to read! Hah! Better write only the part which is getting error.

Comment: @KashishArora the thing is that i'm not receiving any error, its just that any events that occur in the usercontrol are not raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if anybody needs this here it is:
-my btnClick event was not triggered because i was adding the controls on the page to late (onprerender).
FIX:
-added controls OnInit event and everything works great!

Answer (score 0):

Your usercontrol isn't raising an events. Somewhere in your usercontrol you need to define what events you want to raise:

```
' Declare events at module level.
Event TitleChanged()  ' No parameters
Event MySizeChanged(ByVal Width As Double, ByVal Height As Double)
```

Then add the code to Raise the event in the appropriate place:

```
Public Property Title As String
    Get
        Return _title
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If value IsNot "" Then
            _title = value
            RaiseEvent TitleChanged()
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Width As Double
    Get
        Return _width
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If value > 0 Then
            _width = value
            RaiseEvent MySizeChanged(Me.Width, Me.Height)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: I need to know what events where raised from child controls like buttons or textboxes that i want to use on my form... its not raising or handling custom events my issue, its capturing event raised by buttons or any other server controls. For example if i add a button to a custom user control than i can capture the click event and use it in my page, but when i try to capture a click event from a standard button added on my usercontrol container somehow the event its not captured.

Comment: You have to expose the child events in the same method add custom events.